# SQL, HAVING clause explained

Tags: mysql, sql

can someone please explain how to use the HAVING clause, dumb it down as much as possible. i looked at my texbook, the w3schools, and youtube but i still cant wrap my mind around this. i don't know if im over thinking this but i need to learn this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HAVING is used to filter on aggregations in your GROUP BY.**

For example, to check for duplicate names:

```
SELECT Name FROM Usernames
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Assume we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And have 10 columns with both id and value from 1 to 10:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(4, 4),(5, 5),(6, 6),(7, 7),(8, 8),(9, 9),(10, 10);
```

Try the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `value`>5; -- Get 5 rows
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` HAVING `value`>5; -- Get 5 rows
```

You will get exactly the same results, you can see the HAVING clause can work without GROUP BY clause.

Here's the difference:

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `v`>5;
```

Error #1054 - Unknown column 'v' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` HAVING `v`>5; -- Get 5 rows
```

WHERE clause requires a condition to be a column in a table, but HAVING clause can use both column and alias.

This is because WHERE clause filters data before select, but HAVING clause filters data after select.

So put the conditions in WHERE clause will be more effective if you have many many rows in a table.

Try EXPLAIN to see the key difference:

EXPLAIN SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `value`>5;

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | range | value         | value | 4       | NULL |    5 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN SELECT `value` v FROM `table` having `value`>5;

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | index | NULL          | value | 4       | NULL |   10 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

You can see either WHERE or HAVING uses index, but the rows are different.

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` clause is almost the same as `WHERE` clause BUT keeping in mind the below differences.

**Where Clause:**

1. Where Clause can be used other than Select statement also
2. Where applies to each and single row
3. In where clause the data that fetched from memory according to condition
4. Where is used before GROUP BY clause

Ex:Using Condition for the data in the memory.

**Having Clause:**

1. Having is used only with the SELECT statement.
2. Having applies to summarized rows (summarized with GROUP BY)
3. In having the completed data firstly fetched and then separated according to condition.
4. HAVING clause is used to impose condition on GROUP Function and is used after GROUP BY clause in the query

Ex: when using the avg function and then filter the data like ava(Sales)>0

**Summary:**

`Having` works like `Where` clause with out `Group By` Clause